# SQL graph loop detection

Tags: sql, postgresql

I use PostgreSQL. This is function for traversing a tree in depth. I want to use it to traverse graph. However, there is a problem when there are loops in graph. How can I solve this problem, besides setting the limit of the variable "level"?

```
WITH RECURSIVE t(level,path,ParentId,NodeId) AS 
(
        SELECT 0, NodeID::text, ParentId, NodeId FROM GraphStructure WHERE ParentId IS NULL
    UNION
        SELECT
            level + 1,
            path || ' > ' || GraphStructure.NodeId::text,
            GraphStructure.ParentId,
            GraphStructure.NodeId 
        FROM GraphStructure

        JOIN t 
            ON GraphStructure.ParentId = t.NodeId
            WHERE GraphStructure.Distance = 1
) 
SELECT * FROM t ORDER BY path;
```

Comment: Could you check the node id on parent and child and make sure they're not the same?

Comment: If I understand you correctly, then such a check will detect cycles of length 2.
Otherwise, I can view all the child and parent elements, but how to determine to what level you need to look for them?